# Mathematica, group pairs with common values

Tags: sorting, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to use the `GatherBy` function in Mathematica in order to take the pairs in the list `a={{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {1, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}, {6, 8}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}}` and sort by the pairs that contain the value 1. Ideally, output would look like `Output={ { {1,4},{1,5} } , {{2, 3}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}, {6, 8}, {6, 7}, {7, 8} } }` or something similar where the first element in the output is a list of all elements in `a` containing a 1 and the second element contains all pairs that do not contain a 1.

Comment: Thank you, Yongyi. I found this to work better, `b = GatherBy[a, MemberQ[#, 1] &]` since I will be combining all sets that contain a 1 and so they will not simply be pairs later on in the process. Sorry for leaving that part out. I guess as a corollary, when I get up to grouping based upon the value 4, I use a similar command `b = GatherBy[a, MemberQ[#, 4] &] 
Output:{{{6, 8}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}}, {{1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5}}}` 

but I want the set of lists that contain for to appear first. Any suggestions how?

Answer (score 1):

```
GatherBy[a, #[[1]] == 1 || #[[2]] == 1 &]
```

Answer (score 0):

answering the q in the comment, `Sort` the result to ensure the desired order:

```
a = {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {1, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}, {6, 8}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}};
SortBy[GatherBy[a, MemberQ[#, 2] &], !MemberQ[First@#, 2] &]
```

another approach :

```
Reap[Sow[ # , MemberQ[#, 2]  ] & /@ a, {True, False}] // Last
```

Either yields:

```
{{{{2, 3}, {2, 5}}}, {{{1, 4}, {1, 5}, {3, 4}, {6, 8}, {6, 7}, {7, 
8}}}}
```